# How to split split strings and extract first character from each one to build a new string?

Tags: c#, split

Lets say I have two strings as arguments. Firstname and lastname.
John-Aron as firstname, and Albert as lastname.
I want to split the firstname and lastname if it contains "-" or " ", and then I want to extract the first characters from each of those new strings, and build a new string based on that. Then I want to search inside Active Directory with a Directorysearcher and if it already exists, to take the next available character. So in this example, it would be John-Aron Albert: JAA. If JAA samaccountname is already taken, take a new letter and try again. I have not included any DirectorySearcher in this code. The issue I'm having is building the samaccountname in the first place. Code below is  what I have come up with so far but I'm stuck and I need help. Thanks.

This is what I've tried so far, but I'm stuck and can't get it to work the way I want it to.

```
public static string UsernameGeneration(string firstname, string lastname)
{
    string[] firstnames =null;
    string[] lastnames = null;

    string firstnamepart1 ="";
    string lastnamepart1 ="";

    if(firstname.Contains(" ") || firstname.Contains("-"))
    {
        if(firstname.Contains(" ")){
            firstnames = firstname.Split(" ".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
        if(firstname.Contains("-")){
            firstnames = firstname.Split("-".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
    }
    if(lastname.Contains(" ") || lastname.Contains("-"))
    {
        if(lastname.Contains(" ")){
            lastnames = lastname.Split(" ".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
        if(lastname.Contains("-")){
            lastnames = lastname.Split("-".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
    }

    char[] chars1 = firstnames[0].ToCharArray() + firstnames[1].ToCharArray();
    char[] chars2 = lastnames[0].ToCharArray() + lastnames[0].ToCharArray(); 

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 1; i <=99; i++)
    {

        result.Append(chars1[]);
    }

    
    return "";
}
```

I have gotten this far now:

```
public static string UserNameGeneration(string firstname, string lastname)
{
    string firstNameChars = string.Join("", firstname.Split(new char[] { ' ', '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.First()));
    string lastNameChars = string.Join("", lastname.Split(new char[] { ' ', '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.First()));
    string tempUserName = string.Join("", firstNameChars , lastNameChars);

    using(System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher searcher = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher("(samaccountname="+tempUserName+")"))
    {
        if(searcher.FindAll().Count == 0)
            {
                return tempUserName;
            }
    }

    return "";
}
```

The problem still persists if the username is already taken in AD. I want to somehow take another character from the firstnameChars or lastnameChars and add it to the username instead of the initial if its taken. How can I do that?

Comment: define "take a new letter and try again"

Comment: This is several issues in one. Maybe focus on one: getting the "initial-based" username. What about it doesn't work to your requirements?

Comment: btw without cheking it is [as simple as](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FCRFex) `string.Concat("John-Aron Albert".Split(new string[] { " ", "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x=>x[0]))`

Comment: @Selvin -  I mean to extract another letter from the first string if the first result is already taken in Active Directory.

Comment: @Selvin please see what i added at the bottom of the post, when i tried your code

Comment: If you rely on just 3 characters you will very soon run out of combinations. Instead of trying just more 3-char combinations, you should start out with 3 characters from the first name part and 3 from the last name. If you still hit duplicates, add a trailing number. That's what our company does to handle 5.000+ users.

Comment: Also take into consideration names like `Alexandria Maria Ocasio-Cortez` or `John-Paul Mc Whatnot` which could produce unexpected results.

Comment: @Filburt - Thanks for your advice. Luckily this username generation will only be used for a small amount of external users so it should be fine. This is what the customer wants so it is what is it

Comment: You're asking multiple questions at once. I'm afraid the simple Q&A format of Stackoverflow is not suited for that, and thus these questions are out of scope for this site and will probably be closed. Please separate them into focused questions in separate topics. Read [ask] in the [help] and [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the "JAA" (or "JoArAl") part and maybe not the winner in code beauty:

```
/* uses >= C#8 and
System.Linq;
System.Text.RegularExpressions; */
                    
    var firstName = "John-Aron";
    var lastName = "Albert";

    // picks 1st char of each word
    var initials = new string(Regex.Matches($"{firstName} {lastName}", "(^| |-)[A-Z]")
         .Select(m => m.Value[^1]).ToArray()); // picks "JAA"
    
    // picks 1st+2nd char of each word
    var initialsPlusOne = string.Join("", Regex.Matches($"{firstName} {lastName}", @"(^| |-)\w{2}")
        .Select(m => m.Value[^2..]).ToArray()); // picks "JoArAl"
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any suggestion for how to make it pick another character from the first or lastname if the username is taken..? Some ideas?

Comment: @marius I added a 2nd example for picking first 2 chars from each "word", as described this is for C#8 or higher, since it uses Ranges. For lower langvers one could use 'str.Substring(1)' instead of 'str[^2..]'

Comment: Thanks, very interesting :) I'll look into using something like this. Enjoy the weekend

Answer (score 0):

You can make the splitting more succinct and make it work on a larger variety of names by using LINQ and an array of separators this way:

```
var firstNameChars = string.Join("", firstname.Split(new char[] { ' ', '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.First()));
var lastNameChars = string.Join("", lastname.Split(new char[] { ' ', '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.First()));
var initials = string.Join("", firstNameChars , lastNameChars);
```

But as Selvin mentioned in the comment, you have not defined *how* you want to "take a new letter". So can't help you with that.

Comment: Hello, I tried your version and added it to the bottom of the code. What I mean is, I will take the initials (or tempUserName as I named it), search inside Active Directory for it, and if it's already taken, to user another character from the character array og firstname characters or the lastname characters. So for John-Aron Albert, JAA, it would for example be JRA instead. For example.

Comment: if you want to make more succint you can use : string.Join("",(firstname + " " + lastname).Split(new char[] { ' ', '-' }).Select(x=>x.First()))
But you will lose readability